# Rails: Generated URL has double backslash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails project, in my `index` view, I have a link

```
<%= link_to 'Show all posts', show_all_path %>
```

In `routes.rb`, I have a route:

```
match "show_all" => "Posts#show_all"
```

When I click on that link, it goes from

```
http://<domain name>/my_rails_project
```

to

```
http://<domain name>/my_rails_project//show_all
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering why there are two backslashes in front of `show_all` instead of one. And can I make it so that only one backslash appear?

Answer (score 0):

I think your route needs more information:

```
`match "/:project_name/show_all" => "posts#show_all", :as => "show_all"
```

In your view:

```
link_to 'Show all posts', show_all_path(@project.name)
```

This assumes you have a `@project` variable in the page you're viewing.

Comment: Oh, my `project_name` is fixed anyway (it's the name of my Rails project.) I don't think I should make it a variable, should I?

Comment: I've edited the question to clear any confusion you might have.

Comment: Oh, ok. That makes more sense. Try using "/show_all" in your match statement.

Comment: Makes no difference... still two backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

try use get

```
  get "show_all", :to => 'posts#show_all', as: 'show_all'
```

Comment: Makes no difference... still two backslashes.